# FabricJS - Avoid triggering "canvas.on('mouse:up', function() { ... })" after object end moving

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, listener, fabricjs

Using FabricJS I'm making a canvas with the possibility to add rectangle.
Once a rectangle is added to canvas, it can be dragged in any position.

My problem is that when I stop dragging a rectangle, the event:

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(element) { ... });
```

is triggered, but this is an unwanted behavior.

How can I trigger the event:

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(element) { ... });
```

only when is effectively clicked the left button mouse, and not also when I end dragging object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var _isDragging = false;
var _isMouseDown = false;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function () {
    _isMouseDown = true;
    // other stuff
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function () {
    _isDragging = _isMouseDown;
    // other stuff
})

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(element) {
    _isMouseDown = false;
    var isDragEnd = _isDragging;
    _isDragging = false;
    if (isDragEnd) {
        // code for drag complete
    } else {
        // code for no drag mouse up
    }
    // code for both
});
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `mouse:move` listeners should be avoided
cos the move event is fired on every pixel
see the [fabric.js event inspector sample](http://fabricjs.com/events)

in most cases, you only need to compare
the two click positions of `mousedown` and `mouseup`

```
fabricjs_obj
.on('mousedown', function (event) {
    event.target.dragStart = event.pointer
})

fabricjs_obj
.on('mouseup', function (event) {
    const a = event.target.dragStart
    const b = event.pointer
    const obj = event.target
    if (a.x != b.x || a.y != b.y) {
        console.log('obj dragged: '+obj)
        return // stop event handler
    }
    console.log('obj clicked: '+obj)
    // process click event
})
```